# SecrutityException: requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH on SDK level 33

Tags: android, bluetooth

Our app fires an Intent to enable bluetooth. On Android 13 devices we are getting crashes due to the absence of `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` permission but the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) say this permission is required till sdk version 30 only. The permission required for sdk level 33 should be `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` which we do check for.

Crashlog

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from ProcessRecord{5756fe6 13572:com.u.a/u0a277} (pid=13572, uid=10277) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
       at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2327)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:2114)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5612)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5565)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:709)
       at com.u.a.r.FlowActivity.promptBluetoothPermissions(FlowActivity.java:223)
       at com.u.a.r.FlowActivity.onStart(FlowActivity.java:158)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1679)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8471)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4125)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2506)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:242)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:374)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8911)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:671)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:951)
```

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion you build for?

Comment: targetSdkVersion=33

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the full manifest, just in case we are missing something?